# Unable to call C++ binary using subprocess.Popen method

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, subprocess, popen

```
> subprocess.Popen("ADK -j 50 - ordNode jira1disa2 -a '-noControl -sourceDir /some/path/given/' > logFile.log 2>&1 &")
```

I have written almost same query as mentioned above.
`ADK` is one C++ binary along with some argument as options and I am trying to run it through python script in server.

When I put the line :

```
> ADK -j 50 - ordNode jira1disa2 -a '-noControl -sourceDir /some/path/given/' > logFile.log 2>&1 &
```

In one `.sh` file and run that file using Python I am able to execute the result, but while calling directly I am getting error like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 47, in <module>
  check_timezone()
  File "test.py", line 40, in check_timezone
  count = subprocess.check_output(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
  process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception-
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Limitation:

I can't use shell=True

I also tried by giving it in a list with all in strings but that also failed, in `subprocess.Popen` along with so many possible way...
Please suggest a way with which it will work.

Comment: You need to pass a list, but you don't have the convenience of input/output redirection with `<` and `>` there (this only works with `shell=True`). You will have to use the facilities provided by `Popen` to handle input and output.

Comment: The primary problem is, as @blubberdiblub said, that's not how you do redirection with [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with list as well. But that didnt worked

Comment: ["ADK", "-j", "50", "-ordNode", "jira1disa2", "-a", '-noControl -sourceDir /some/path/given/', ">", "logFile.log", "2>&1", "&"]  This also failed to run and throws the same error.